# Comma before "either" at end of this sentence

Tags: commas, sentence-ends

Please help me determine whether or not to include a comma at the end of the third sentence:

> "I won't be talking to my ex at the party tonight."
>
> -"But what if she talks to you?"
>
> "I won't be listening to her either."

-or-

> "I won't be talking to my ex at the party tonight."
>
> -"But what if she talks to you?"
>
> "I won't be listening to her, either."

Thanks!

Comment: It depends.  If it makes it clearer, add a comma.  If not, leave it out.

Comment: I will punctuate the silence, with commas.

Answer (score 0):

It's the opposite of the previous comment.  Without the comma emphasizes the word 'listening', in accordance with simultaneously not talking to her.  With the comma, there's an  emphasis on 'her' which implies that the speaker won't listen to her equally to not listening to another person.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Without the comma it means that he won’t listen to her - the same way as he won’t listen to anyone else. With the comma it means that he won’t talk and won’t listen to her. So yes, here the comma makes sense.